# What does /proc/PID/sessionid mean on a Linux machine?

Tags: session

On an Ubuntu Linux 20.04, `cat /proc/$$/sessionid` shows `3`, and on an openSUSE 15.5, it shows `2`.

The `3` or `2` definitely has different meaning that the session ID value (SID) from `getsid(0)`, then what does it mean?

[image: Ubuntu screenshot]

[image: openSUSE screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/procfs-audit_loginuid

```
What:       Audit Login Session ID
Date:       2008-03-13
KernelVersion:  2.6.25-rc7 1e0bd7550ea9 ("[PATCH] export sessionid alongside the loginuid in procfs")
Contact:    linux-audit@redhat.com
Users:      audit and login applications
Description:
        The /proc/$pid/sessionid pseudofile is read to get the
        audit login session ID of process $pid as a decimal
        unsigned int (%u, u32).  It is set automatically,
        serially assigned with each new login.
```

Comment: Wow, yes. With each telnet/ssh login, I see different `/proc/$$/sessionid` value.